# Confused about Twitter Javascript API

Tags: javascript, twitter

The samples I do find online are all about using the Twitter button.

Reading the [Twitter Post API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) it's not clear where to place the code. It seems they are just telling the params expected, but not how the code should look like

I'm soooo confused with this API (:

Well, my need is to place my on my own website my own button. When the user clicked on it, I want to call my a Javascript function that should do the following:

1) Check if any user is logged in
2) Login, if not
3) Check if my Twitter App is already installed on the logged in user
4) Request permission, if not
5) Post a message on his timeline

In fact, I don't even know if I need a Twitter App in order for people to post on their own timeline from my website?

Anyhow, I'm looking for something I can put on a single JavaScript function and that does not involved any Twitter specific button.

I would imagine this to be the simplest of any Twitter APIs but somehow all samples I keep finding online refer to use the Twitter button.